# touch events aren't fired

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I faced with the problem. If you tap next to the link (close, but not on the link), `touchend` event won't be fired, only `mouseup`. If you tap right on the link, two events will be triggered.

html:

```
<a id="link" href="#">link</a>
```

js:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');

link.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    console.log('mouseup');
});

link.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    console.log('touchend');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj02zmz5/) (use dev tools device mode)

Is it some browser's issue or it's described in the specification?

Answer (score 0):

Well javascript has a method preventDefault() that prevent to be called a default event over the object who has triggered the event.

`link.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    console.log('touchend');
    e.preventDefault();
});`

If does still not work, you should add an event click to catch that up to prevent follow that link.

Hope that helps.